# Unexpected '[' on return explode(" ", $message)[0];

Tags: php

In PHP, I'm getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['" on the following line of code:

```
return explode(" ", $message)[0];
```

I'd give more details, but that's really about it. The line looks unimpeachable to me, and in fact was running fine until I copied it into another file. The biggest difference is that now that line is part of a class, and that it's being called by a big software library that I don't know much about. What could be causing this issue?

A bit more context:

```
public function getIRCCommand($message)
{
    if ($message[0] != ":")
    {
        return explode(" ", $message)[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return preg_split("/\s+/", $message)[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the previous line.

Comment: @pickypg Curly brace. It's in an if statement.

Comment: This feature has only been [introduced in PHP 5.5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php). Are you sure you're not running 5.4 or lower?

Comment: @Carsten That seems to have been it, thanks. Go ahead and add that as an answer if you like. Never would have even suspected that was the problem.

Comment: @JackM Sorry, I was wrong. This has been possible since PHP 5.4. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely running on PHP 5.3 or lower. You need to upgrade to at least PHP 5.4 to get this working (or use a temporary variable to access elements of a function returning an array).

What you're doing there is called [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88). The manual says:

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.
>
> As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

And, to check that, let's try to run

```
<?php
echo explode(" ", "1 2 3")[1];
```

[for all kinds of diferent PHP versions](http://3v4l.org/qrLW6). The results are, that PHP versions 5.4 and hihgher output "2", which would be your desired result.